# Java Builder pattern with Generic type bounds

Tags: java, generics, builder, type-safety

I'm attempting to create a class with many parameters, using a Builder pattern rather than telescoping constructors.  I'm doing this in the way described by Joshua Bloch's Effective Java, having private constructor on the enclosing class, and a public static Builder class.  The Builder class ensures the object is in a consistent state before calling build(), at which point it delegates the construction of the enclosing object to the private constructor.  Thus

```
public class Foo {

    // Many variables

    private Foo(Builder b) {
        // Use all of b's variables to initialize self
    }

    public static final class Builder {

        public Builder(/* required variables */) {

        }

        public Builder var1(Var var) {
            // set it
            return this;
        }

        public Foo build() {
            return new Foo(this);
        }

    }

}
```

I then want to add type bounds to some of the variables, and thus need to parametrize the class definition.  I want the bounds of the Foo class to be the same as that of the Builder class.

```
public class Foo<Q extends Quantity> {

    private final Unit<Q> units;
    // Many variables

    private Foo(Builder<Q> b) {
        // Use all of b's variables to initialize self
    }

    public static final class Builder<Q extends Quantity> {
        private Unit<Q> units;

        public Builder(/* required variables */) {

        }

        public Builder units(Unit<Q> units) {
            this.units = units;
            return this;
        }

        public Foo build() {
            return new Foo<Q>(this);
        }

    }

}
```

This compiles fine, but the compiler is allowing me to do things I feel should be compiler errors.  E.g.

```
public static final Foo.Builder<Acceleration> x_Body_AccelField =
        new Foo.Builder<Acceleration>()
        .units(SI.METER)
        .build();
```

Here the units argument is not `Unit<Acceleration>` but `Unit<Length>`, but it is still accepted by the compiler.

What am I doing wrong here?  I want to ensure at compile time that the unit types match up correctly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`units` should return `Builder<Q>`, not an ungenerified `Builder`.

Answer (score 0):

Although @Daniel's point is valid, still the error in your code is spotted by Eclipse at least. Of course, your definition of `Quantity`, `Unit` and `METER` is probably different from the simplistic hack I put together:

```
interface Quantity {
}
class Acceleration implements Quantity {
}
class Length implements Quantity {
}
public class Unit<Q extends Quantity> {
    public static final Unit<Length> METER = new Unit<Length>();
}

public static final Foo.Builder<Acceleration> x_Body_AccelField =
    new Foo.Builder<Acceleration>()
    .units(Unit.METER) // here the compiler complains
    .build();
```

The error message is:

```
The method units(Unit<Acceleration>) in the type Foo.Builder<Acceleration> is
not applicable for the arguments (Unit<Length>)
```

Comment: Interesting.  I was using NetBeans, which did not complain.  The unit etc hierarchy I'm using come from JSR 275 (http://download.java.net/maven/2/net/java/dev/jsr-275/jsr-275/1.0-beta-2/) and JScience (http://jscience.org/)

Comment: You should be getting that error even in NetBeans... if not, that's a very bad bug. The difference in your original code is if you have an intermediate property: new Foo.Builder<Acceleration>().cheese(GOUDA).units(Unit.METER), where the 'cheese' method returns Builder not Builder<Q>.